# Android: Enabling Touch Tones in emulator

Tags: android, touch, audio

Is it possible to hear touch tones (tones the Android OS plays when touching something like a button or list item, etc. ... not touch tones related to dialing a phone) on the Android emulator.  I know the OS on the emulator has an option for it and I've enabled it, however, I still don't hear anything.

Thanks,
Harry